# How can I return a number based on a skewed normal distribution?

Tags: c#, probability-density

If I want to get `e^x` as you can see in this figure

[image]

which I can just call `Math.Exp(x);`

What I want to do make a function that returns `y` for my own graph (like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Negative_and_positive_skew_diagrams_(English).svg/446px-Negative_and_positive_skew_diagrams_(English).svg.png)) which is a normal distribution skewed left or right or not skewed at all. It will have some standard deviation and some maximum height.

I've been googling and thinking about how to do it for a while but my math skills just aren't good enough. I was hoping I could get some help with this.

Comment: So do you want the value of the probability density function at some `x`? Then just implement the formula…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I've come across answers that show how to generate random numbers according to a random distribution but I don't know how to implement the actual formula. What is the formula?

Comment: now that's a different question. It's not an "If I want to get e of x" type of formula then. (that would be simply the value of a function at some point). It seems that you want to generate numbers with relative frequency described by a probability density function. For that, you have to determine the cumulative distribution function of the distribution and use the difference between its value at certain points as the relative frequency coefficient(-ish) of your random numbers.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry for my confusing comment above.  You understood what I wanted correctly the first time.

Anyway I now understand what you meant by your first answer. There's a formula for the probability density function as I found here: https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-normal-pdf.php

I had no clue that there was a formula but now after seeing the formula I vaguely remember learning it in the statistics course I took nearly 2 years ago. I feel a bit stupid now.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

First, a skewed normal random point(x) will be created, then probability distribution function (PDF) of that point will be found.

The math used here depends on Ermak and Nasstrom's 1995 [study](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/26/055/26055147.pdf). If you like, take a look to sample fortran77 code exists in this publication (Most of the variable names used in the code do not fit C# naming conventions, simply because I wanted the reader to relate them to the original paper).

```
  private static double GetSkewedRandomNumber(double standardDeviation=1, double skewness=0, int dbIteration = 10)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var variance = Math.Pow(standardDeviation, 2);
        const double a = 2.236067977; // --> Square root of 5
        const double b = 0.222222222;
        const double c = 243 / 32;
        double finalrun, sumdbran = 0;
        double dbmom3, dbmean1, dbmean2, dbprob1, dbdelta1, dbdelta2, randomNumber1, randomNumber2, dbran, terma, termb;

        dbmom3 = Math.Sqrt(dbIteration) * skewness * Math.Pow(variance, 1.5);
        terma = b / variance;
        termb = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dbmom3, 2) + c * Math.Pow(variance, 3));
        dbmean1 = terma * (dbmom3 - termb);
        dbmean2 = terma * (dbmom3 + termb);
        dbprob1 = dbmean2 / (2 * a * dbmean1 * (dbmean1 - dbmean2));
        dbdelta1 = -a * dbmean1;
        dbdelta2 = a * dbmean2;

        //Loop for summation of double block random numbers in each final random number
        for (int i = 0; i < dbIteration; i++)
        {
            randomNumber1 = random.NextDouble();
            randomNumber2 = random.NextDouble();

            if (randomNumber1 < (2 * dbdelta1 * dbprob1))
                dbran = dbmean1 + (2 * dbdelta1 * (randomNumber2 - 0.5));
            else
                dbran = dbmean2 + (2 * dbdelta2 * (randomNumber2 - 0.5));

            //sumdbran is the sum of double block random numbers created by the iteration
            sumdbran = sumdbran + dbran;
        }

        //Calculate final skewed normal random number
        finalrun = sumdbran / Math.Sqrt(dbIteration);

        return finalrun;
    }
```

and below code is for PDF:

```
  public static double GetPDF(double mean, double standardDeviation, double skewness, double x)
    {
        var pdf = 0d;
        var variable = skewness * x;
        var normalPDF = NormalDistribution.GetPDF(0, 1, x);
        var normalCDF = NormalDistribution.GetCDF(0, 1, variable);
        pdf = 2 * normalPDF * normalCDF;
        return pdf;
    }
```

You can implement NormalDistribution.GetPDF and NormalDistribution.GetCDF methods yourself (mentioned in GetPDF method). They are simply calculating Probability Density Funciton and Cumulative Distribution Function of a normal distribution. To make it simple and focus on the question I prefered not to add the code. For those who also want to check CDF calculation of the skewed normal distribution please check [here](https://github.com/armaganderman/Dopamin)

Here is an example of a skewed distribution derived from above code and its relevant pdf-cdf graphs.

[pdf graph of positive (+0.75) skewed normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj443.png)

[pdf graph of negative (-0.75) skewed normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/617XP.png)

[cdf graph of positive (0.75) skewed normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlNG6.png)

[cdf graph of negative (-0.75) skewed normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjc9W.png)