# Implementing probability density formula for skewed normal distribution in C#

Tags: c#, statistics, distribution, finance

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128781/whats-the-formula-for-the-probability-density-function-of-skewed-normal-distribu) a while ago on math.stackexchange.

I was given the formula for the pdf of a skewed normal distribution but it involves integrals and I have no clue how to implement the formula in C#.

Like I said in the question linked, I'm writing a program where certain 'effects' are strong in the beginning and weaker later on or vice-versa. I've opted to use a skewed standard distribution.

I just want a formula where I input the skewness, 'x' and get the density for that particular x on the graph.

If I can understand how to implement the formula he gave perhaps I can also use it for non-standard distributions where the mean and standard deviation are something other than 0 and 1 respectively.

I checked out Math.NET but was unable to find something that could help me here. I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return a number based on a skewed normal distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255822/how-can-i-return-a-number-based-on-a-skewed-normal-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to numerically solve integrals, with a few methods being more popular than others. A simple google search for "numerically solve integrals" will probably be more beneficial than a solitary answer here.

If you're looking for an example specifically in c#, [this link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Numerical_Integration#C.23) will provide implementation in c# for a definite integral for the mid-point, simpson, and trapezoidal methods to solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The integral mentioned in [flawr's answer to your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1128788/134754) is, as he/she says, the cdf of the normal distribution. There is a simple formula for that, namely Phi(x) = 1/2 (1 + erf(x/sqrt(2))), where erf is the Gaussian error function, which is commonly included in math libraries; I don't know about .Net in particular.

You don't have to compute the integral numerically; just find erf in some library. In fact, computing the integral numerically is almost certainly going to be less accurate than using erf from a library, and it will certainly be more work.

EDIT: [Answers for this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834998/what-reference-should-i-use-to-use-erf-erfc-function) seem to suggest that [this implementation of erf for C#](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/csharp_erf/) is useful.